# Dealing with Popup in Corona game engine

Tags: popup, coronasdk

I have a screen in Corona to display a puzzle, and once user guess the correct answer, I'm going to display a simple pop up on the screen to do the congratulation a long with close button to dismiss the popup, now I need for a simple work around to disable any control or behaviour on the original screen while displaying the popup, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this by stop or pause [transitions](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/index.html), [timers](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html) and animations etc. before you go to scene with pop up.

Comment: both the game screen and the popup are in the same scene in my case.

Comment: So in this case you also need block interaction with scene to prevent this I would remove event listeners or add variable to check if pop up is visible to stop execute code from it. In my previous game I use [overlay](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/showOverlay.html) to show score after player lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can add transparent rectangle from transparent image file (not just rectangle, as it will not be touchable).

Size of this rectangle must be the size of all screen.

Position of rectangle - under your popup (or better make it as part of your popup).

Add listeners to this rectangle on touch and tap that will just return false - so it will prevent any clicks under it.

That will save you from pausing / disabling buttons, that you don't want to disable/pause.